# array count() issue

Tags: php

```
$nialiakhirpraktikum = $ntugasakhir+$ratarata; //from other process 
if ($nialiakhirpraktikum>79) { $grade="A"; } 
else if ($nialiakhirpraktikum<=79 AND $nialiakhirpraktikum>67) { $grade="B"; } 
else if ($nialiakhirpraktikum<=67 AND $nialiakhirpraktikum>55) { $grade="C"; } 
else if ($nialiakhirpraktikum<=55 AND $nialiakhirpraktikum>44) { $grade="D"; } 
else { $grade="E"; }     
$array = array($grade); 
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

I have some result in array like this:

```
Array ( [B] => 1 ) 
Array ( [B] => 1 ) 
Array ( [C] => 1 ) 
Array ( [C] => 1 ) 
Array ( [B] => 1 ) 
Array ( [B] => 1 ) 
Array ( [B] => 1 ) 
Array ( [B] => 1 ) 
Array ( [B] => 1 ) 
Array ( [B] => 1 )
```

how to get result as following:

```
score for B = 8

score for C = 2
```

Comment: I assume there is actually an array containing these associative arrays?

Comment: are you talking about 2-d array?

Comment: @AlvinWong it is the result that loop in the array. hard to say it in English. :(

Comment: @Najiullah.com then please show is in code  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sub arrays contain only 1 items, you can use following code.

```
array_count_values(array_map('key', $array));
```

Here,

- [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) Counts all the values of an array
- [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays
- [`key()`](http://php.net/key) Fetch a key from an array

[**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/wAnHos)

#### Update

As your are just looping its better you initialize `$array` before the loop and then add items to it. After the loop ends invoke `array_count_values`.

```
$array = array(); // initialize before loop
for(...){   /// sample loop
   // your original code
   $array[] = $grade;  // add grades here
}
$grade_distribution = array_count_values($array); // count it

foreach($grade_distribution as $g => $count)
    echo "score for $g = $count\n";
```

Comment: my code for : "array('B' => '1'), array('B'=>'1'), array('B' => '1'), array("C"=>"1"), array('C'=>'1')" is from looping. code in the first question is final result. how to replace that?

Comment: My php code: 
    $nialiakhirpraktikum = $ntugasakhir+$ratarata; //from other process

 if ($nialiakhirpraktikum>79)
    {
  $grade="A";
 }
    else if ($nialiakhirpraktikum<=79 AND $nialiakhirpraktikum>67)
 {
     $grade="B";
 }
    else if ($nialiakhirpraktikum<=67 AND $nialiakhirpraktikum>55)
 {
     $grade="C";
 }
    else if ($nialiakhirpraktikum<=55 AND $nialiakhirpraktikum>44)
 {
     $grade="D";
 }
    else
 {
        $grade="E"; 
 } 
    $array = array($grade);
    print_r(array_count_values($array));

Comment: thanks for your edit and your code. but my result just show like this: score for B = 1
whats wrong? i follow your instruction and fail.. :(

Comment: thanks for your help. my problem is solved... like your instruction. i just wrong put $array = array(); before loop start. :p thanks for your help. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will return the sum for a particular letter:

```
function getTotal($key, $array) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($array as $currentArray) {
        foreach ($currentArray as $currentKey => $currentValue) {
            if ($key === $currentKey) {
                $total += $currentValue;
            }
        }
    }
    return $total;
}
```

Then use it like:

```
$totalForB = getTotal('B', $myArray);
```

Comment: Or use [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

Comment: @WaleedKhan, that will work if all values are 1, but I was inferring from his example that he wanted to count the actual value of a letter, not just the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$base=array(array("B"=>1),array("C"=>1),array("B"=>1),array("B"=>1),array("C"=>1));
print_r($base); // just to debug
$score=array_reduce($base,function(&$rst,$i){
    foreach($i as $k=>$s){
        if(empty($rst[$k])){
            $rst[$k]=0;
        }
        $rst[$k]+=$s;
    }
    return $rst;
},array());
print_r($score);
```

output of `print_r($base)`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [B] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [C] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [B] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [B] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [C] => 1
        )

)
```

output of `print_r($score)`:

```
Array
(
    [B] => 3
    [C] => 2
)
```

Comment: thanks @passerby i will try it... :) but how to echo the result?

Comment: @Najiullah.com I'm not sure if I understand you...`$score` contains scores for each key (as I've `print_r` in the last line). I'll update the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: my code for : $base=array(your array in the example on top);

how to replace "your array in the example on top" using my code? because my code is a result from looping.

Comment: @Najiullah.com Try to demonstrate how are you getting the result in your question so that we can help accordingly -- we all are now assuming you _have already had that array at hand_.

Comment: a very,very,very,very quick response from all members. I am confused as to which one to answer first. :( ok everyone, I will try all the code that you provide. I say many thanks to you all. :)